# Dockerized Django Backend Not Receiving Certain Requests When Accessed Via Nginx

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, docker-image

I'm working on a Docker-based project with a Django backend, a React frontend, and an Nginx server acting as a reverse proxy to the Django backend. The project is structured with separate Dockerfiles for each component (frontend, backend, nginx_backend_server) and managed using docker-compose.

Issue:

When I run my Django backend using

> docker-compose up --build

, it appears that the backend does not receive certain requests, or some data is missing in the response. Interestingly, when I run the Django server directly using **python manage.py runserver**, everything works as expected.

Backend Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.8
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
CMD gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:8000 --worker-class=gevent --worker-connections=1000 --workers=5 backend.wsgi
```

Nginx Configuration for Backend Server:

```
server {
    listen 8000;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://backend:8000;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3"
services:
  backend:
    build: ./backend
    volumes:
      - ./backend:/app
      - ./data:/app/data
  ...
```

Attempts to Resolve:

Verified that all Docker volumes are correctly mounted.
Checked the Nginx configuration for potential misconfigurations.
Ensured that all environment variables and dependencies are correctly set up.
Question:

What could be causing the backend to not receive certain requests or data when run in a Docker environment, as opposed to running it directly with python manage.py runserver? Are there any additional configurations or logs that I should check to diagnose this issue?